# How to classify Japanese characters as either kanji or kana?

Tags: java, unicode, cjk

Given the text below, how can I classify each character as [kana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kana) or [kanji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji)?

誰か確認上記これらのフ

To get some thing like this

```
誰 - kanji
か - kana
確 - kanji
認 - kanji 
上 - kanji 
記 - kanji 
こ - kana 
れ - kana
ら - kana
の - kana
フ - kana
```

(Sorry if I did it incorrectly.)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'split'?

Comment: Updated question to make the goal more clear.

Comment: Hieroglyphs are an ancient Egyptian form of text.  They have nothing to do with modern Japanese forms of text.

Comment: @alex2k8 - we understand what you mean by "splitting" now.  But that is not what splitting means.  What you are really trying to do is "classify" Japanese characters (not hieroglyphs!!) as either Kanji or Kana.  (Splitting implies putting the characters into different piles / collections ...)

Comment: @alex2k8: you want to differentiate between "ideograms" and "syllabaries" (? plural of "syllabary"). A kana is a syllabary: both katakana and hiragana are syllabaries.  As Stephen C said (+1), hieroglyphs have nothing to do here ;)   It really shouldn't be hard for there are only about 60 hiragana and 60 katakana (I used to know them ;)

Comment: Thank you all for clarifications.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This functionality is built into the [Character.UnicodeBlock](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html) class. Some examples of the Unicode blocks related to the Japanese language:

```
Character.UnicodeBlock.of('誰') == CJK_UNIFIED_IDEOGRAPHS
Character.UnicodeBlock.of('か') == HIRAGANA
Character.UnicodeBlock.of('フ') == KATAKANA
Character.UnicodeBlock.of('ﾌ') == HALFWIDTH_AND_FULLWIDTH_FORMS
Character.UnicodeBlock.of('！') == HALFWIDTH_AND_FULLWIDTH_FORMS
Character.UnicodeBlock.of('。') == CJK_SYMBOLS_AND_PUNCTUATION
```

But, as always, the devil is in the details:

```
Character.UnicodeBlock.of('Ａ') == HALFWIDTH_AND_FULLWIDTH_FORMS
```

where `Ａ` is the full-width character. So this is in the same category as the halfwidth Katakana `ﾌ` above. Note that the full-width `Ａ` is different from the normal (half-width) `A`:

```
Character.UnicodeBlock.of('A') == BASIC_LATIN
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about that.

Comment: but CJK_UNIFIED_IDEOGRAPHS isn't found be default, I assume an additional import statement is needed, beyond that needed for Character.

Answer (score 14):

Use a table like [this](http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml) one to determine which unicode values are used for katakana and kanji, then you can simply cast the character to an int and check where it belongs, something like

```
int val = (int)て;
if (val >= 0x3040 && val <= 0x309f)
  return KATAKANA
..
```

Comment: Note that jleedev has essentially the same method, but using a table provided by the JVM.

Answer (score 6):

This seems like it'd be an interesting use for [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [CharMatcher](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) class. Using the tables linked in Jack's answer, I created this:

```
public class JapaneseCharMatchers {
  public static final CharMatcher HIRAGANA = 
      CharMatcher.inRange((char) 0x3040, (char) 0x309f);

  public static final CharMatcher KATAKANA = 
      CharMatcher.inRange((char) 0x30a0, (char) 0x30ff);

  public static final CharMatcher KANA = HIRAGANA.or(KATAKANA);

  public static final CharMatcher KANJI = 
      CharMatcher.inRange((char) 0x4e00, (char) 0x9faf);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("誰か確認上記これらのフ");
  }

  private static void test(String string) {
    System.out.println(string);
    System.out.println("Hiragana: " + HIRAGANA.retainFrom(string));
    System.out.println("Katakana: " + KATAKANA.retainFrom(string));
    System.out.println("Kana: " + KANA.retainFrom(string));
    System.out.println("Kanji: " + KANJI.retainFrom(string));
  }
}
```

Running this prints the expected:

> 誰か確認上記これらのフ
>
> Hiragana: かこれらの
>
> Katakana: フ
>
> Kana: かこれらのフ
>
> Kanji: 誰確認上記

This gives you a lot of power for working with Japanese text by defining the rules for determining if a character is in one of these groups in an object that can not only do a lot of useful things itself, but can also be used with other APIs such as Guava's `Splitter` class.

**Edit:**

Based on jleedev's answer, you could also write a method like:

```
public static CharMatcher inUnicodeBlock(final Character.UnicodeBlock block) {
  return new CharMatcher() {
    public boolean matches(char c) {
      return Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) == block;
    }
  };
}
```

and use it like:

```
CharMatcher HIRAGANA = inUnicodeBlock(Character.UnicodeBlock.HIRAGANA);
```

I think this might be a bit slower than the other version though.

Comment: Right, if you only want to test for membership in a specific range, it might be faster to do it yourself. Surprisingly, the UnicodeBlock class doesn’t have a method to test a character for membership, and it seems the only way is its static `of` method, which loops through every block until it finds one.

Answer (score 4):

You need to get a reference that gives the separate ranges for kana and kanji characters. From what I've seen, alphabets and equivalents typically get a block of characters.

Comment: Well, in Unicode Kanji has a range of U+4E00 to U+9FBF, Katakana has a range of U+30A0 to U+30FF and Hiragana has a range of U+3040 to U+309F. With that 'splitting' text should be easy, depending on what splitting actually is.

Comment: This isn't as easy as it sounds, because there are multiple ranges for each.

Answer (score -1):

I know you didn't ask for VBA, but here is the VBA flavor for those who want to know:

Here's a function that will do it. It will break down the sentence like you have above into a single cell. You might need to add some error checking for how you want to deal with line breaks or English characters, etc. but this should be a good start.

```
Function KanjiKanaBreakdown(ByVal text As String) As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim kanjiCode As Long
Dim result As String
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To Len(text)
    If Asc(Mid$(text, i, 1)) > -30562 And Asc(Mid$(text, i, 1)) < -950 Then
        result = (result & (Mid$(text, i, 1)) & (" - kanji") & vbLf)
    Else
        result = (result & (Mid$(text, i, 1)) & (" - kana") & vbLf)
    End If
Next

KanjiKanaBreakdown = result
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```